# How do I return a list of my folders with the files inside?

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.fileinfo

I am wondering how can I return the list of my folders with the files inside.

Because I can't return both of the list...and can't put both types in the list.

```
    public List<DirectoryInfo> GetTopFolders()
    {
        List<DirectoryInfo> Folders = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
        List<FileInfo> Files = new List<FileInfo>();

        System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C://inetpub//wwwroot//Files//");
        di.GetDirectories();
        System.IO.FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles();

        foreach (DirectoryInfo t in di.GetDirectories())
        {
            Folders.Add(t);
            foreach (FileInfo f in di.GetFiles())
            {
                Files.Add(f);
            }
        }
        return Folders;
    }
```

This is the code I am actually using.

Comment: You can't return two different types. If directory and folder paths/names are enough, you can add them to a `List<string>` and return that.

Comment: You could separate the functions. One without parameters that return the `Folders` and a second one with your `Folders` list as parameter that returns the `Files`

Comment: `FileInfo` has `FullName`, `Name` and `Directory` properties - seems this is everything you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a two-tuple. See [Tuple.Create on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387181.aspx)

```
public Tuple<List<DirectoryInfo>,List<FileInfo>> GetTopFolders()
{
    List<DirectoryInfo> Folders = new List<DirectoryInfo>();
    List<FileInfo> Files = new List<FileInfo>();

     /* All your other code here */
     /* Removed for brevity*/
    foreach (DirectoryInfo t in di.GetDirectories())
    {
        Folders.Add(t);
        foreach (FileInfo f in di.GetFiles())
        {
            Files.Add(f);
        }
    }
    return Tuple.Create(Folders, Files);
}
```

You use it like this:

```
var fileAndFolders = GetTopFolders()
fileAndFolders.Item1 //will be your folders of type List<DirectoryInfo>
fileAndFolders.Item2 //will be your folders of type List<FileInfo>
```

Comment: @Oded not sure I see what would go wrong. My answer is to his generic question _"How do I return two types from a function"_

Answer (score 5):

Well, both FileInfo and DirectoryInfo inherit from [FileSystemInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.aspx).  So you could maintain a list of that type instead and return the whole lot together:

```
public List<FileSystemInfo> GetTopFoldersAndFiles()
{
    List<FileSystemInfo> FilesAndFolders = new List<FileSystemInfo>();

    System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C://inetpub//wwwroot//Files//");
    di.GetDirectories();
    System.IO.FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo t in di.GetDirectories())
    {
        FilesAndFolders.Add(t);
        foreach (FileInfo f in di.GetFiles())
        {
            FilesAndFolders.Add(f);
        }
    }
    return FilesAndFolders;
}
```

Of course you might need some conditional handling in the code where you make use of this object based on each item's type.

Comment: +1 this is infact a more elegant solution! :) To get the specific class' properties he will have to cast though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, List<FileInfo>>`:

```
private Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, List<FileInfo>> GetTopFolders()
{
    Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, List<FileInfo>> r = new Dictionary<DirectoryInfo, List<FileInfo>>();


    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C://inetpub//wwwroot//Files//"); 
    di.GetDirectories();

    r.Add(di, di.GetFiles().ToList());

    foreach (DirectoryInfo t in di.GetDirectories()) 
    {
        r.Add(t, t.GetFiles().ToList());
    } 

    return r; 
}
```

then you can list your folders and files like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (KeyValuePair<DirectoryInfo, List<FileInfo>> item in GetTopFolders())
{
    sb.AppendLine(item.Key.FullName);

    foreach (FileInfo file in item.Value)
    {
        sb.AppendLine("\t" + file.Name);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```